# Max Number of Post Versions Supported

Tags: revisions

We are running a news site based on WP 3.5.1. Some editors complain that the WYSIWYG editor on the post editing page is not working properly for some posts. The editing buttons are not shown.

In some cases we need to update a post many times (like more than 500 times).
May it be the cause?
What will happen to these posts if I set `WP_POST_REVISIONS` to 10?
Will old versions be deleted automatically, or will they remain?

Comment: IIRC when you have a large number of revisions, then set a threshold lower only once the post is updated will the oldest be purged.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `WP_POST_REVISIONS` to a fixed number. If you don’t, WordPress will keep an unlimited number of revisions. See function `wp_revisions_to_keep()`:

```
function wp_revisions_to_keep( $post ) {
    $num = WP_POST_REVISIONS;

    if ( true === $num )
        $num = -1;
    else
        $num = intval( $num );

    if ( ! post_type_supports( $post->post_type, 'revisions' ) )
        $num = 0;

    return (int) apply_filters( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', $num, $post );
}
```

On the other hand … if you need such a high number of changes you should revisit the *edit work flow*. There are surely ways to get this number down.

Comment: hi, what's "edit work flow"?

Comment: @mustafa The process for editing your posts. There seem to be too many steps in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

To address:

> What will happen to these posts if I set WP_POST_REVISIONS to 10?
>   Will old versions be deleted automatically, or will they remain?

You have this action:

```
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'wp_save_post_revision' );
```

set by default in `/wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

If you check the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L4911) of `wp_save_post_revision()` you can see that it will delete the remaining revisions of the current post:

```
$delete = count($revisions) - WP_POST_REVISIONS;
```

with `wp_delete_post_revision()` when the hook `pre_post_update` is activated for a given `$post_id`, except when it is performing an auto-saving.

Here is the relevant part from the source of `wp_save_post_revision()`:

```
// WP_POST_REVISIONS = true (default), -1
if ( !is_numeric( WP_POST_REVISIONS ) || WP_POST_REVISIONS < 0 )
        return $return;

// all revisions and (possibly) one autosave
$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions( $post_id, array( 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

// WP_POST_REVISIONS = (int) (# of autosaves to save)
$delete = count($revisions) - WP_POST_REVISIONS;

if ( $delete < 1 )
        return $return;

$revisions = array_slice( $revisions, 0, $delete );

for ( $i = 0; isset($revisions[$i]); $i++ ) {
        if ( false !== strpos( $revisions[$i]->post_name, 'autosave' ) )
                continue;
        wp_delete_post_revision( $revisions[$i]->ID );
}
```